# Floating Numbers Appear Reversed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Why floating numbers are reversed in some mobile phones in Flutter apps?

I have wrapped my whole app with `Directionality` with `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl` to make the app suitable for Arabic users, but in some cases, users find the floating numbers reversed, although it works fine on my mobile and with all mobiles that I have tested with.

You can check the website from (http://arabeia.web.app/).

Attached image figure out the issue:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the ```textDirection: TextDirection.ltr``` in your text widget?